# Complex series with product of two sequences problem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that if the complex series $\sum_{\nu =1}^\infty u_\nu$ converges and the 
real sequence $(a_{\nu})_{\nu=1}^\infty$ is non-negative and decreasing, then $$\Big|\sum_{\nu =k+1}^\infty u_\nu a_\nu\Big|\leq a_{k+1}M_k,$$
where
$$M_k=\sup_{n\geq k+1}\Big|\sum_{\nu=k+1}^n u_\nu\Big|.$$

I have been trying to prove this for a while using summation by parts, but I haven't been able to get very far. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in the definition of $M_k$ the supremum should be taken over $n \geqslant k+1$, not over $n \leqslant k+1$. With the summation by parts, how far have you got?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I fixed it now.

Comment: My hint would be $S_{\nu} = S_k + (S_{\nu} - S_k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a helpful hint from @DanielFischer, I managed to figure it out.

By summation by parts, for $n\geq k+1$, we have $$\Biggl\lvert\sum_{\nu =k+1}^n u_\nu a_\nu\Biggr\rvert = \Biggl\lvert t_na_{n+1}-t_ka_{k+1}+\sum_{\nu=k+1}^n t_\nu(a_\nu-a_{\nu +1})\Biggr\rvert\,,$$
where $t_\nu=\sum_{\mu=1}^\nu u_\nu$. We write
\begin{align}
\sum_{\nu=k+1}^n t_\nu(a_\nu-a_{\nu +1}) &= \sum_{\nu=k+1}^n t_k(a_\nu-a_{\nu +1})+\sum_{\nu =k+1}^n (t_\nu -t_k)(a_\nu-a_{\nu +1}) \\
&=t_k(a_{k+1}-a_{n+1})+\sum_{\nu =k+1}^n (t_\nu -t_k)(a_\nu-a_{\nu +1}),
\end{align}
and since $a_\nu-a_{\nu+1}\geq 0$, we have
\begin{align}
\Biggl\lvert t_na_{n+1}-t_ka_{k+1}+\sum_{\nu=k+1}^n t_\nu(a_\nu-a_{\nu +1})\Biggr\rvert &= \Biggl\lvert (t_n-t_k)a_{n+1}+\sum_{\nu=k+1}^n(t_\nu-t_k)(a_\nu-a_{\nu+1})\Biggr\rvert \\
&\leq \lvert t_n-t_k\rvert a_{n+1} + \sum_{\nu=k+1}^n \lvert t_\nu-t_k\rvert (a_\nu-a_{\nu+1}).
\end{align}
Now, since $M_k=\sup_{n\geq k+1} \lvert t_n-t_k\rvert$, it follows that
\begin{align}
\lvert t_n-t_k\rvert a_{n+1} + \sum_{\nu=k+1}^n \lvert t_\nu-t_k\rvert (a_\nu-a_{\nu+1})
&\leq M_k\Biggl(a_{n+1}+\sum_{\nu=k+1}^n (a_\nu-a_{\nu +1})\Biggr) \\
&= M_k(a_{n+1}+a_{k+1}-a_{n+1}) \\
&= M_ka_{k+1}.
\end{align}

Comment: I've edited to use the `align` environment because I think it's nicer with that. Feel free to roll back if you disagree.